# Django how to send an email to the drivers after viewing thier form submission?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am newbie and just see the  django documentation of sending mail . i want to send an email to the drivers  after seeing their details if they are eligible i want them to send an email using thier email address that they submit while registering to my app . please tell me how do i send a email. i had already set the settings.py email host user all the needs of send an email its working on my other app . but not working on this app . how do i get the driver email and send an email from our company employee.

**Views.py**

@csrf_protect

```
def rentacar_carapp_sendmail(request):
    if request.POST:
        try:
            args['driver'] = driver = Driver.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('driver_id'))
            subject = "Please Register Your Car"
            from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            to_email = carapp.get('car_app_driver_id.driver_email')
            join_message = """thankyou  we will contact you later """
            send_mail(subject=subject, from_email=from_email, recipient_list=[to_email], message=join_message,
                    fail_silently=False)

            driver.save()
        except:
            pass
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/mega-admin/rentacar/driver-manager/')
```

**Models.py**

```
class Driver(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = "driver"
        verbose_name = "Driver"
        verbose_name_plural = "Drivers"
        ordering = ['driver_firstname', 'driver_lastname']

    driver_firstname = models.CharField(
        max_length=64,
        blank=False,
        null=False
    )
    driver_lastname = models.CharField(
        max_length=64,
        blank=False,
        null=False
    )
    driver_email = models.EmailField(
        blank=False
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

Read this link, this should handle your problem: [How to work with ajax request with Django](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html)

**Small example code:**

*My html:*

```
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="emailaddress">
<a class="button" type="submit" id="hire_car" value="{{ customer_id }}">Submit button for the customer</a>
```

*Ajax call:*

```
<script>
$("#hire_car").on('click', function () {
            var customer = ($(this).attr('value'));

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '{% host_url 'rentacar_carapp_sendmail' host 'your_host_name' %}',
                data: {customer: customer},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('Success');
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

If you don't understand the host_url in the Ajax call, please read the [documentation](https://django-hosts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

*urls.py*

```
 url(r'^rentacar_carapp_sendmail$', views.rentacar_carapp_sendmail, name='rentacar_carapp_sendmail'),
```

*Send_mail view:*

```
def rentacar_carapp_sendmail(request):
customer = Driver.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('customer'))
customer_email = customer.email

# Send mail to customer
subject = "Please Register Your Car"
message = "thankyou  we will contact you later"
email_from = "your email" \
email_to = (customer_email)

send_mail(subject, message, email_from, email_to, fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: @P de Boer i didnt understand dont know how do i implement it in my view. can you tell me the view of mine .

Comment: @Shko I've made some changes. Hope it will work for you now.

Comment: No it is not getting driver id and email

Comment: Can you give me more information? It's hard to tell what is wrong if I have to assume what is happening.. Did you correctly implement the ajax call, so did you receive POST values? What is for eg `request.POST.get('customer'))` returning?

Comment: P. de Boer Can i have your skype id . ill show you on call ?

Comment: Hy @P.de Boer? There